# What version of jquery do i use for my script

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I was looking to find out what version of jquery do i used based on the following script that my friend wrote for me, unfortunately he is on holiday so I can't get in touch with him.

I have added the following code within my body tag and then calling it below that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.top_cols_hide_arrow').click(function() {
              $('.finishing_top_cols_hide').toggle("top");
        });

       $('.top_cols_hide_arrow').click(function(){
       $(this).toggleClass('active');
   });
    });
```

and the HTML part:

```
<div class="finishing_top_cols_hide_arrow_mn">
<span class="finishing_top_cols_hide_arrow">open</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to run this on my localhost but whenever I click the arrow nothing happens and then I realised that I dont really have a script source for this to function and I'm not sure what I need to link to, in order to get this to work.

If somebody could please advise.

Comment: What makes you think that wrong jQuery version is the problem? If that's all the relevant code, the problem is that you're targeting class `top_cols_hide_arrow` but the class in the HTML is `finishing_top_cols_hide_arrow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

The code that your friend wrote for you is simple so most of Jquery versions will support it.